# PHP: insert array with seperate lines into database as values

Tags: php

I am passing an array through ajax to PHP where I want to insert them as a row in mysql. Is there a way i can do that?

Javascript:

```
var textarray = [];
for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
  var sms = $('#TxtMessage').val();
  var brand = data[i].brand;
  var type = data[i].type;
  var csvLine = `${sms}, ${brand}, ${type} `;
  textarray.push(csvLine)
}

var resultCSV = textarray.join('\n');

//Pass the array to PHP
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../php/functions.php",
  data: { results: resultCSV },
  success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
  }
});
```

In PHP i would like to insert each row into mysql database.
The values I pass to PHP look like this

```
sample text, Toyota, 30/10/2008 10:00:00 
sample text, Nissan, 17/02/2021 14:00:00
```

so each row of the text should go in as a row into the database.

PHP:

```
$myArray = $_POST['results'];
$columns = implode(" ",array_keys($myArray));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($myArray));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `databasetable`($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code so far that is receiving the AJAX data?

Comment: You tagged it as PHP and shown non of it...

Comment: sorry, It wasnt working so didnt include it. Added it in now

Comment: I don't follow the new line issue. Could you please provide more details on that?

Comment: Unrelated to current question but for best practices: You should change your datetime to the mysql format. You also should upgrade your PHP version (presuming this code even works currently). `mysql_*` was removed from the last +4 versions and has been depreciated for the +2 versions before that. With a newer driver prepared statements with parameterized queries should be used.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind imploding column names with a space, rather than a comma like you did for the values? Plus, your values are not quoted. All of this could be avoided by using a newer library (`mysqli` or `PDO`) and prepared, parametrized queries.

Comment: Another point: no need to convert your JS array to a string before sending. Just send the array under the `results` key.

Comment: @user3783243, each line should go into the database as a separate row, so inserts as one row sample text, Toyota, 30/10/2008 10:00:00 and sample text, Nissan, 17/02/2021 14:00:00 into next row and so on. I am imploding them with space so I can get them into separate values? is there a way to pass that data into the db. I am sure i am doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

What people usually do is use something like json to encode and decode their data they pass.  It is much easier than what you are doing.

You encode like

```
$myVar = json_encode($dataArray);
```

You decode like

```
$myReturn = json_decode($_POST['csvDataArray']);
```

If you want to convert csv to array you can use

```
$mycsvArray = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
```

You may have to stripslashes.

Then it is as simple as looping to build your query. Something like this.

```
$myQuery = array();
foreach($myCSVArray as $rowArray) {
  $myQuery[] = INSERT INTO `databasetable`($columns) VALUES ($escaped_values);
}
```